# Silverlight change button text

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a button with multiple contetnt. I want to change it's text when the button is clicked.

XAML:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" Margin="33,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Style="{StaticResource GlassButtonStyle}" FontSize="26.667" Click="Button_Click_1" Name="button1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Height="69" Stroke="Black" Width="69">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.004,1.044" StartPoint="0.739,0.25">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

                <ContentPresenter Content="Clicke me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

C# code:

```
button1.Content = "Hello world";
```

This makes the rectangle disappear, though I want only to change the text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the [Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of Button to show your rectangle all the time.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" Margin="33,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Style="{StaticResource GlassButtonStyle}" FontSize="26.667" Click="Button_Click_1" Name="button1" Content="Click Me">
<Button.Template>
<ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Height="69" Stroke="Black" Width="69">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.004,1.044" StartPoint="0.739,0.25">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </StackPanel>

</ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
</Button>
```

See [Using Control Templates to Customize a Control's Look and Feel](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx)